# addind a jpanel created on a different class to the main view page while using mvc

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jframe

What I want to do is create a general window that will contain all the elements that are common for the whole program (example a menu bar, background etc), and add the corresponding panels when a button is clicked. I am using MVC pattern on this project and on view package, I have created two classes, `gui`(extending `JFrame`) and `login` (`JPanel` with text fields). When clicking the `login` button on `gui`, the `login` `JPanel` should appear.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    protected JLabel user;
    protected JButton login;
    protected JPanel panel;
    public GUI(){
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(); // create FlowLayout
        Container container = getContentPane(); // get container to layout
        setLayout( layout ); // set frame layout
        setSize(800,800);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Main Frame");
        this.setVisible(true);
        panel = new JPanel();
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu view = new JMenu("View");
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenu options = new JMenu("Options");
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        user = new JLabel("(user not logged)");
        user.setForeground(Color.gray);
        login = new JButton("Login");
        JMenuItem print = new JMenuItem("Print");
        this.add(panel);
        panel.add(menuBar);
        panel.add(user);
        panel.add(login);
        layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        menuBar.add(file);
        file.add(print);
        menuBar.add(view);
        menuBar.add(options);
        menuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        menuBar.add(help);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
    public JButton getButton(){
        return login;
    }
}
```

And here's the `login` class code:

```
public class Login{

    private JButton log;
    private JButton clear;
    protected JPanel login;

    public Login(){

    }
    public void logIn(){
        login = new JPanel();
        JLabel userName = new JLabel("User Name: ");
        JLabel psd = new JLabel("Password: ");
        JTextField user = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
        log = new JButton("Log in");
        clear = new JButton("Exit");
        login.add(userName);
        login.add(psd);
        login.add(user);
        login.add(password);
        login.add(log);
        login.add(clear);
    }
    public JButton getButton(){
        return log;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine until here. Then on controllers package I have this code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import mvc.model.*;
import mvc.view.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Actions {
    private GUI gui;
    private Login login;
    private ActionListener actionListener;

    public Actions(GUI gui, Login login){
        this.gui = gui;
        this.login = login;
    }
    public void control(){        
        actionListener = new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {                  
                  loginButtonAction();
              }

              private void loginButtonAction() {
                  gui.add(login);//should add the panel but shows an error
              }
        };                
        gui.getButton().addActionListener(actionListener);   
    }
}
```

It says that `Login` cannot be converted to `popupmenu/component`.
I also tried to extend `JFrame` for the `login` class, but it said that it couldn't load a window into a container. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> it says that Login cannot be converted to popupmenu/component.

This error is pretty self-explanatory. It states that `Login` class is not a [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) which is true:

```
public class Login { // it doesn't extend from Component
   ...
}
```

You can add a public method to return the `JPanel` you need like this:

```
public class Login{
   ...
   public JPanel getLoginPanel() {
       return login;
   }
}
```

And then make this change in `Control` class:

```
  private void loginButtonAction() {
      gui.add(login.getLoginPanel());
  }
```

---

> also tried to extend jframe on login class but it said that it
>   couldn't load a window into a container.

You get this error because [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) extends from [Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) and it's a top-level container. As such it cannot be added to other containers.

---

#### Edit

> it shows me a `NullPointerException` at:
>
> ```
> public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
>     loginButtonAction();// here's the exception
> }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> gui.add(login.getLoginPanel());
> ```

Make sure both `gui` and `login` are properly initialized when you do this call: `gui.add(login.getLoginPanel())`. Note `Login` class members are not initialized untill `logIn()`method is called from the outside. So if you do something like this:

```
Login login = new Login();
Actions actions = new Actions(someGuiInstance, login);
```

It will throw a NPE because there's no call to `login.logIn()` method to initialize its class memmers.

Comment: it shows me a NullPointerException at
    `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {                  
                  loginButtonAction();// here's the exception
              }`
and 
    `gui.add(login.getLoginPanel());`